# Trying to stop jQuery click event as long as animation works

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, conditional-statements

I have a content slider, additionally I made "prev" & "next" buttons. The buttons should only be clickable when the animation is complete (animations duration is 500ms). I tried to solve it with the :animated selector, but it won't work:

```
if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
    $(".nextItems a").click(function() {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').parent().next().find("a").addClass('selected');
    });
}
if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
    $(".prevItems a").click(function() {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').parent().prev().find("a").addClass('selected');
    });
}
```

Or quite simply, I need to stop the buttons click event for 500ms after a click. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: make use of `.unbind()` method http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: @aSeptik binding and then unbinding and then rebinding is bad. Its much better to use a flag or check to decide if you should handle the event rather than do the (un)binding dance.

Comment: @PetersenDidIt - yes you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the if statement that checks if the thing is animated inside your click event handler:

```
$(".nextItems a").click(function() {
    if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').parent().next().find("a").addClass('selected');
    }
});

$(".prevItems a").click(function() {
    if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').parent().prev().find("a").addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Also you could dry out your code by doing something like this:

```
$(".nextItems a").click(function() {
    nextPrevItem('next');
});

$(".prevItems a").click(function() {
    nextPrevItem('prev');
});
function nextPrevItem( direction ) {
    if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected')
            .parent()[ direction ]()
            .find("a").addClass('selected');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right! The if statement has to be inside the event. But your second solution beats everything! Great! That's why you did it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need the if statement inside the handlers:

```
$(".nextItems a").click(function() {
    if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').parent().next().find("a").addClass('selected');
    }
});

$(".prevItems a").click(function() {
    if (!$(".scrollContainer").is(':animated')) {
        $(".slideNavig").find('a.selected').removeClass('selected').parent().prev().find("a").addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.delay()` (available in jQuery 1.4 and higher) or you can use `.setTimeOut()`.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/settimeout-15-6-2010

http://api.jquery.com/delay/